# c++ - How to solve that two libraries implement the same interface?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

We are trying to make Basler (pylon API) and LUCID (arena API) cameras work at the same time by the same application (c++, visual studio).

The issue is that both of them implement the genicam interface. It seems that only one can be used (the first to be included implements Genicam and populates the namespace):

This is the sample code where only the LUCID/Arena is imported

```cpp
#include "Arena/ArenaApi.h"
#include "Arena/Arena.h"
void main(){
    Arena::ISystem* pSystem = Arena::OpenSystem();
    pSystem->UpdateDevices(100);
    std::vector<Arena::DeviceInfo> deviceInfos = pSystem->GetDevices();
    try
    {
        std::cout << "cams " << deviceInfos.size() << "\n";
        if (deviceInfos.size() > 0)
        {
            Arena::IDevice* pDevice = pSystem->CreateDevice(deviceInfos[0]);

            auto nodemap = pDevice->GetNodeMap();// This is a GenApi_3_3_LUCID::INodeMap *
        }
     }
}
```

This is when both libraries are imported (and the pylon first)

```cpp
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>

#include "Arena/ArenaApi.h"
#include "Arena/Arena.h"
void main(){
    Arena::ISystem* pSystem = Arena::OpenSystem();
    pSystem->UpdateDevices(100);
    std::vector<Arena::DeviceInfo> deviceInfos = pSystem->GetDevices();
    try
    {
        std::cout << "cams " << deviceInfos.size() << "\n";
        if (deviceInfos.size() > 0)
        {
            Arena::IDevice* pDevice = pSystem->CreateDevice(deviceInfos[0]);

            auto nodemap = pDevice->GetNodeMap();// This is a GenApi_3_1_Basler_pylon::INodeMap *
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I get away with having both libraries at the same time:

- Would a DLL do the trick? My idea is to take the Arena out of my main project and built it as a DLL. But I cannot properly understand the documentation and I do not know if it would keep the device alive inside the DLL. In other words, my main application would only call a function like "open camera" (which do not return anything to the main application) and "take photo" (returning an OpenCV mat) but internally the DLL should keep variables like camera stream, resolution... Is that a possibility?
- I've read about Isolated Applications (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/concepts-of-isolated-applications-and-side-by-side-assemblies?view=msvc-170) but I have no idea if this may suit me.

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

After trying some of the answers proposed, I've found that the issue seems to be even before the #include in the code. The first inclusion in the visual studio's configuration (C/C++ -> General -> Additional directories of inclusion) gets the "genapi namespace" (causing problems at linking time). For example, if the pylon is added first in the include of visual studio I will not be able to execute anything from the Arena, even if I do not add:

```cpp
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
```

At any point of the code (so the first snipped will not work if the first include in the configuration is the pylon.

**END IMPORTANT EDIT**

Thank you,

Comment: No pictures of code please, could you copy and paste it in to your question?

Comment: Never tried it but maybe this might be an approach https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/06/03/static-linking-c-plus-plus/

Comment: Also show the *#include*s for those 2 pieces of code.

Comment: @Mehno Thanks for your comment. The problem is that the library is not "mine" thus I cannot decide their defines, or namespace use.

Comment: That is what this link was all about. Either i did not understood the approach or you did not understand it. The author suggested to use the implementation in two different source files and use a wrapped class in the header with different namespace. Am i mistaken here? You can just use the libs in these source files and use the header files that you create.

Comment: @Mehno While trying out what the author says, I have realized that no matter what I do the first include in the visual studio's configuration (C/C++ -> General -> Additional directories of inclusion) gets the "genapi namespace" and thus the linker does not find the right function in the DLL. For example if the pylon is added first in the include of visual studio I will not be able to execute anything from the Arena (even if I do not add the
 ```c++
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
```

Comment: I did not have time to investigate the root cause, but compiling piece of my application that uses ArenaSDK as one static library, using PylonSDK as another static library and than using it from the main app worked fine.